# Cannot load image from nib on iPad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator, xib

I'm getting the `cannot load image referenced from a nib in the bundle` error on iPad simulator, it works fine on iPhone simulator. As far as I can tell everything is hooked up correctly, what could be the cause of this?

Some background: I just inherited this app from a company, it is coded using xibs, and some autolayout and size classes. It was coded only for iPhone and I'm trying to migrate it over to iPad, but most of the images from the xibs won't load. I don't have much experience with xibs or size classes, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up migrating all the images over into an asset catalog and it all worked fine... quite bizarre!